# Use Field Component to set state with object inside

Tags: reactjs

i have a component with this state:

```
state = {
  data: {
   name: ...,
   place: ...,
   responsible: {
     name: ...,
     mail: ....
   }
 }
}
```

i have a component Field that onChange it update the state with event:

```
handleOnSave = (id, data) => {
    if (this.state[id] !== data) {
      const newData = {
          ...this.state.data,
          [id]: data,
        };
       this.setState({data: newData})
    }
}
```

how can i if i want change responsible object inside data of state? I mean, with this function i change state = { place: 'newPlace' }, i need change an object: responsible

Comment: use `this.setState()`, for example: `this.setState({place: 'newPlace'});`

Comment: Lol, i do that, but i didn't paste.

Comment: i setState with new value that arrive on attribute, but when i have to edit responsible object inside state, how can do this automatically ?

Comment: how can i check if the field that im changing is a responsible field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can call `handleOnSave` passing an object, example: 
`handleOnSave({name: 'name'})` or `handleOnSave({responsible: {name: 'name'}})`

```js
handleOnSave = ({responsible, ...rest}) => {
  const newData = {
    ...this.state.data, ...rest,
    responsible: {
      ...this.state.data.responsible, ...responsible
    }
  };
  this.setState({data: newData});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to merge the value. Use callback overload version of `setState`

```
this.setState((state, props) => ({
    data: {
        ...state.data,
        responsible: data.data.responsible
    }
});
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html